# How to write a yaml in python for multiple test cases?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, robotframework, pyyaml

I am learning Robot framework using python. I am looking for ways to pass data to two different test cases. In java, this was easy. I made a class for yaml and gave the data for two separate test cases in the yaml file. How can I have such an architecture in Python? When I try to give the data in yaml file, I am getting duplicate key error.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, and also suggest ways to give data to multiple test cases using single yaml?
[Java_yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dba5V.png)
[Python_yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSPcG.png)

Comment: Yes someone can tell you what is wrong, but it is difficult to see from the screenshot (you should really cut and paste the content, replacing the strings that should stay hidden), so that people that want to help you can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please don't provide links to pictures of your data. Please take the time to copy, paste, and format it as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are getting a duplicate key error? Because with the
input you present you'll get a mapping values are not allowed here error:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
Get_Request
  alias : 'amway1'
  session_url : 'url2'

Post_Request
    alias : 'amway2'
    session_url : 'url2'
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
try:
    data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

which gives:

```
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 9:
      alias : 'amway1'
            ^ (line: 2)
```

This is because you try to use a multi-line plain scalar as the key at
the start of that YAML, and those are not allowed (they have to be simple, not multi-line).
You probably forgot to insert a colon (`:`) after the `Get_Request` and `Post_Request`.

```
Get_Request:
  alias : 'amway1'
  session_url : 'url2'

Post_Request:
  alias : 'amway2'
  session_url : 'url2'
```

(You should also consistently indent your YAML, with the same amount
of spaces before the keys, now you have 2 and 4 positions. That is not
necessary to make valid YAML, and the parser will accept it, but it is
to properly see the structure when humans inspect your input).